# Football/Soccer club entity-relationship diagram. Is there anything wrong or that can be improved?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

I want to create a db to store my soccer/football team (Xerez) data. I have made an entity-relationship diagram (with no cardinalities), but I am wondering if it is correct.

This is the diagram:

[image]

Next, I will explain the diagram, so you can better understand the case:

- About Xerez club managers (all in the history) I need to know the name, football name, born and death dates, born city, number of matches managed, won, draw and lost, a picture and his career as manager, this is, previous/next clubs (name) and the season (year), nothing else about the career.
- About player, I need to know the same information than for managers, but also the position, number of goals scored, minutes played, number of yellow and red cards and a comment. Please note, that both for managers and players, I am only interested in his statistic with Xerez, no other clubs. About the club career I only need to know the club name and the season.
- About each Xerez season (I don't mind about other teams), I want to know the year, the manager/s, players, what matches were played, number of matches, final place in league and final result (relegation, promotion...)
- About each match, I need to know the date, the competition class (league format, cup format or single friendly match), the match class (official or friendly), tier for match leagues (first division, second...), league group (1, 2...), tournament name (Copa del Rey, Trofeo de la Vendimia...), edition number of the tournament (for pre-season tournaments), week for league matches and round for cup matches, teams which played the match taking into account if they were the home or away team, badge of those teams, final result of the match, referee, who scored in the match and on what minute, who played the match being important to know if they were in the line up or in the bench, number of minutes played, minute on which they entered the pitch or they were substituted, if they got a yellow/red card and the minute, and for what team they played (home or away), managers of both teams, a chronicle of the match from a website/newspaper, stadium, city and observations.

My questions are:

- Is there anything wrong?
- Can this be improved? (most probably, as I have no much knowledge about dbs).

Thank you so much!

Comment: This looks interesting indeed. Please could you tell me what pre use notation you use in this diagram.